# [LIBGDX][Android] Bug if I press 2 fingers on the screen?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touch

I've developed a game on LibGDX and ported it to android so I had to make on screen controls but recently I discovered (through the android dev tools) that when I continually touch the button to go left and try to jump it sometimes don't work register the jump touch. It doesn't register when the Y coordinates for both touches are more or less the same.

-Sorry I can't explain it any better.

P.S.: The phone is brand new, my fingers are clean and the screen has a protective coat and is also clean.

UPDATE: I tried to remove the protective coat for the screen and it worked perfectly. Probably some kind of air bubble near on jump button or something.

Here are my on screen controls (just in case):

```
    //BTW I use the camera to get a viewport of 1280x780 for all resolutions so I have to convert screen coordinates to world coordinates
    //Begin SpriteBatch
    sb.begin();

    sb.draw(websiteBanner, 0, 0, Camera.originalRes.x * Camera.cameraScale.x* Camera.resolutionRatio.x, Camera.androidControlsOffset* Camera.resolutionRatio.y);

    //On screen controls textures
    sb.draw(goLeftRightButton, 0, 0, controlsWidth* Camera.resolutionRatio.x, Camera.androidControlsOffset* Camera.resolutionRatio.y);
    sb.draw(duckButton, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - (controlsWidth)*Camera.resolutionRatio.x, 0, controlsWidth / 2* Camera.resolutionRatio.x, Camera.androidControlsOffset* Camera.resolutionRatio.y);
    sb.draw(jumpButton, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - (controlsWidth / 2)*Camera.resolutionRatio.x, 0, controlsWidth / 2* Camera.resolutionRatio.x, Camera.androidControlsOffset* Camera.resolutionRatio.y);

    sb.end();

    boolean goLeftTest = false;
    boolean goRightTest = false;
    boolean duckTest = false;
    boolean jumpTest = false;

    //maximum of 4 fingers at a time
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {
            //Utils.pointInsideBox uses the Rectangle class from badlogic and 
            //goLeft
            if (!goLeftTest && Utils.pointInsideBox(Gdx.input.getX(i) / Camera.resolutionRatio.x, (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY(i)) / Camera.resolutionRatio.y, 0, 0, controlsWidth / 2, Camera.androidControlsOffset)) {
                goLeftTest = true;
            }

            //goRight
            if (!goRightTest && Utils.pointInsideBox(Gdx.input.getX(i) / Camera.resolutionRatio.x, (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY(i)) / Camera.resolutionRatio.y, controlsWidth / 2, 0, controlsWidth / 2, Camera.androidControlsOffset)) {
                goRightTest = true;
            }

            //Duck
            if (!duckTest && Utils.pointInsideBox(Gdx.input.getX(i) / Camera.resolutionRatio.x, (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY(i)) / Camera.resolutionRatio.y, Camera.originalRes.x * Camera.cameraScale.x - controlsWidth, 0, controlsWidth / 2, Camera.androidControlsOffset)) {
                duckTest = true;
            }

            //Jump
            if (!jumpTest && Utils.pointInsideBox(Gdx.input.getX(i) / Camera.resolutionRatio.x, (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY(i)) / Camera.resolutionRatio.y, Camera.originalRes.x * Camera.cameraScale.x - controlsWidth / 2, 0, controlsWidth / 2, Camera.androidControlsOffset)) {
                jumpTest = true;
            }
        }
    }

    //Replace the booleans
    goLeft = goLeftTest;
    goRight = goRightTest;
    duck = duckTest;
    jump = jumpTest;
```

Comment: then show us your (also clean I assume :) ) Listener you are using

Comment: Diagnosis:  Yes that's a bug.  Probably a bug in your code.

Comment: it that case you should for sure firstly check app on other device. By the way I reccomend you [Scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) because witing own click listener seems to be to me not a very good idea